# How do I create my own .php file with a code part and echo it on different pages?

Tags: php, theme-development

I'll start with an example:

Echoing `get_header();` will echo the content of `header.php` 
The same with `get_footer();` (echos all the content of `footer.php`).

How do I create myown.php file in my directory and use `echo get_myown();` to display content?

I am working on a website and don't want to repeat code.

(I **don't want** to use `do_shortcode()`)

Comment: at which places do you want to show this content ?

Comment: lets say i have a template `page-contactus.php` and i want to out output a code in this php file exactly how i echo `echo get_footer();` (which outputs the content of `footer.php`

Comment: if you have a file `page-contactus.php` you juste need to call `get_template_part("page-contactus");`

Comment: without `echo`? i want to echo the content of `myown.php` inside `page-contactus.pgp`

Comment: @mmm if you have an answer you should post it as an answer and not a comment, you're depriving yourself and the asker of reputation, while making answers harder to find

Comment: @TomJNowell you have done the redaction work very well then I upvote your answer and I upvote the question too.

Comment: @mmm thanks but please refrain from answering in the comments in future

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There's a fundamental misunderstanding here about how partials/templates that aren't full pages/template fragments in WP work.

`get_*` is not how files are loaded, and `get_header` and `get_footer` are special cases for legacy reasons, kept for conventions sake.

They're actually equivalent to:

```
get_template_part( 'header' );
get_template_part( 'footer' );
```

But with some additional filters and checks so that older code doesn't break. ( [see here](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_header/) )

So the answer would be:

```
get_template_part( 'myown' );
```

Only do this for templates though, if you have a library or PHP file that defines functions, classes, anything other than a template, use the standard PHP `require` and `include` statements.

> (I don't want to use do_shortcode())

Usually when people ask this question, they have actual pages with content that they want to embed code into, say halfway down a blog post, or at the top of a page. Shortcodes allow this to happen, which is why they're a very common answer. But if you've defined a shortcode, you don't need to call `do_shortcode()`, just call the function directly.